# What's the advantage of dynamic forms in angular?

Tags: angular

I have learned template driven forms and reactive forms.But I am confused for dynamic forms.Why need I use it?I can't image the application scenarios of dynamic forms.

Who can give a application scenarios where the dynamic forms is a best choice.

Comment: so questionnaires survey is that scenario,fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario given by the official Angular website is pretty good.

Example requirements: You need to ask questions to job applicants.

- Every job type needs different questions
- Questions need to be able to change rapidly
- Questions need to be able to change without a developer being present/aware

This calls for a "management" interface of some sort to create/edit/delete questions.
Without changing the code on the frontend these questions need to be loaded for the user.

Dynamic forms are perfect for this, you can build the form with the (meta)data you receive from your api. With your management interface you have control over your frontend form without need for a developer to code extra form elements.

Answer (score 0):

**Advantages of Reactive Forms**

1. More flexible, but needs a lot of practice
2. Handles any complex scenarios
3. No data binding is done (immutable data model preferred by most developers)
4. More component code and less HTML markup
5. Easier unit testing